# python regular expression through each member of a list

Tags: python, regex, expression

From these two lists:

```
list_A = ["eyes", "clothes", "body" "etc"]
list_B = ["xxxx_eyes", "xxx_zzz", "xxxxx_bbbb_zzzz_clothes" ]
```

I want to populate a third list wit those objects from 2nd list, only if some part of his names matchs one of the names from the first list.

In the previous example, the third list has to be:

```
["xxxx_eyes", "xxxxx_bbbb_zzzz_clothes"]
```

Comment: Let's say that `list_B` contains "xxx_ccc_clothesline".  Should that go into the third list, because "clothes" is in `list_A`, or not, because it's not a separate word?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a regex? A string find will also suit your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a list comprehension, this will work:

```
list_C = [word for word in list_B if any(test in word for test in list_A)]
```

Comment: Depending on how the OP feels about the behaviour of `in`, and on whether "_" could be in any word in `list_A`, I might use something like `[word for word in list_B if set_A & set(word.split('_'))]` instead, but without feedback there's no way to know.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use regexs for this:

```
search = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, list_A))).search
result = filter(search, list_B)
```

Although Blender's answer might be enough in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: list_A = ["eyes", "clothes", "body" "etc"]

In [2]: list_B = ["xxxx_eyes", "xxx_zzz", "xxxxx_bbbb_zzzz_clothes" ]

In [7]: [x for x in list_B if any(y in list_A for y in x.split('_'))]
Out[7]: ['xxxx_eyes', 'xxxxx_bbbb_zzzz_clothes']
```

Comment: ? `True if y in list_A else False` is simply `y in list_A`.

Comment: I guess I removed that while you were commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Slowest but simplest would be:

```
list_A = ["eyes", "clothes", "body" "etc"]
list_B = ["xxxx_eyes", "xxx_zzz", "xxxxx_bbbb_zzzz_clothes" ]

list_C=[]
for _ in list_A:
    for __ in list_B:
        if _ in __:
            list_C.append(__)
```

Comment: Why the use of underscores?  "a" and "b" would not only be clearer, it'd actually be shorter!  Usually `_` is only used as a variable name to mean "this is a dummy variable we're not going to do anything with".  Second, this could give multiple copies of the same element of `list_B` if it contained multiple members of `list_A`, which I'm not sure was intended.

Comment: yeah, to remove duplicates "set(list_C)". Thanks for pointing.